Automatically copying the formula whenever I INSERT rows IN BETWEEN rows, not at the end of the row
What I want to happen is that whenever someone insert a new row in between rows, the formula would have also copied there instead of dragging the column again and again.
Here's the code that we're using:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D4="","",(sum(IF(D4<300, 0, ROUNDUP(IF(D4<3648, (((D4+100)*0.465)+200), (((D4+100)*0.48)+150))))))))


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchage. To learn the ropes this site, please start by reading the [tour].

If your sheet has a header row and computes the same function down each column, you can achieve the desired behaviour by spilling an arrayformula out of the header row like this:
={"title";arrayformula(...)}

If you then insert rows anywhere below the header row, the arrayformula will still apply.
It's impossible to be more specific without further context being provided. Also, I'm not sure the arrayformula or sum in your example are actually doing anything - both appear to be redundant.

In Google Sheets, inserting a formula automatically could be done by add-ons or Google Apps Script.
A Google Sheets add-on is a small app that extends the built-in features. This could be found and installed from the Extensions menu.
Google Apps Script is an automation platform that is integrated in Google Sheets and other Google apps. It uses JavaScript as programming languages and includes services to make it easier to automate tasks. To learn more go https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.
It's worth to mention that for automatically insert formula when a new row is inserted you will need an on change installable trigger. To learn about installable triggers in Google Apps Script go to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.
